# What happens if I decide to skip saving?

Tags: dnd-4e, saving-throw

What happens if I am afflicted with a condition that worsens on a failed save and choose not to try to save? Do I:

- Automatically suffer the effects of the failed save?
- Keep my current condition?
- Have no choice and must roll the save regardless?

This came up in a game earlier this afternoon when we decided to just stop saving against the effect that was causing us to fall unconscious.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**There is no option to skip saving throws at the end of your turn.**

From the *Rules Compendium* pg 228

> If a creature is subject to an effect that a save can end, the creature makes a saving throw against that effect at the end of each of its turns.

[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=149) words it thusly

> **End of Turn:** At the end of your turn, you make a saving throw against each effect on you that a save can end.

I don't see any room for a player to argue that Saving Throws are optional in any way.  Do remember that only end of turn saving throws can trigger effects that worsen on a failed save.  If your character can get extra saving throws in some way, then those throws will not penalize you if failed.

Comment: Perfect, especially the reminder about conditions not worsening except at end of turn saves.

Answer (score 3):

While it might not be RAW to forgo a save, it makes a lot of sense to me that you could choose to automatically fail a save and suffer it's effects.  A good example of this is the save that you get when falling off a cliff; if you want to not fall, you get a save, but if you *do* want to fall for whatever reason, it makes little sense that you have to save yourself.  While it might not be totally realistic that you can willingly take the negative effects of things like poison or mental debilitation, I feel like it can make some narrative sense for the heroes to fall victim so some effect, if they needed to.

A note, though:  If you (or your GM) wants to stick to pure RAW, then Pat's answer is spot on.

Comment: It's a good point.  I was only speaking to the end of turn saving throws and have edited my answer to be more clear on that point.  Saving throws to go into hindering terrain are optional IMHO.